# when i'm trying to view the entire array it gives me a single element

Tags: javascript, scope

trying to create a recursive function that will take 2 parameters , starting number and a larger ending number and then it will count down / up (it really doesn't matter ) .. i created an array to push - unshift the smaller number into and they i get the function to call it self again

```
function recursiveCountUp(startNum, endNum) {
let storageArray = [];

if(startNum>endNum)
{return [endNum];}
else{
         
storageArray.unshift(startNum);
recursiveCountUp((startNum+1),endNum);
        
}

return  console.log(storageArray);

}
  
recursiveCountUp(4,11);

i get the result as 
[ 11 ]
[ 10 ]
[ 9 ]
[ 8 ]
[ 7 ]
[ 6 ]
[ 5 ]
[ 4 ]
```

when i globally declared the array before the function i was able to ask for the array outside the loop and get the desired output from the function

```
let arrayRange = [];

function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {

if(startNum>endNum)
{return [endNum];}
else{
arrayRange.push(startNum);
rangeOfNumbers((startNum+1),endNum);

}

}
`
rangeOfNumbers(4,11);

console.log(arrayRange);`
```

.. i understand that i'm getting the result a number by number as the function is executing the return every time it is being called

i need help in those two points :

1. to get the full array i need to ask for the array outside the function , i can't do that if the array is declared locally ( in the mini assignment i'm doing it's asking me not to use globally declared variables )
2. why am i getting the result like that : 11 , 10 , 9 ,8 .. etc
   if i use push or i use unshift I'm getting the same result , and the output should start with the starting numb so i expected 4 first then 5 then 6 .. etc

Comment: Why are you using recursion for this?

Comment: [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) positions the element in the front of the array. [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds it to the end.

Comment: you are declaring and initializing the `storageArray` variable everytime inside the function. So it won't make any difference if you do push or unishift on an empty array. If you are willing to explore the recursive approach, you should pass the array itself as an argument so that it will be the state and you won't need to keep track of it in a higher scope

Comment: @DiegoD

ty for pointing that out i think i got it , i'm recreating the variable and thus it will have only one element , the results i'm getting are confusing , i'm getting the end number as the first answer then the 2nd highest number and so forth 


this is my 2nd point that i need to understand .. can u help in that one too ?

Comment: @AndrewParks i'm taking a course (free code camp ) and they have that problem .. it can be solved in an easier way via loops but meh ! i'm not complaining

Comment: @MrasksAlot you already accepted the answer and I'm not sure if those questions remain unanswered.. anyway to address what you asked before, the problem with your recursive function was returning a value only in one of those if branch. Every single recursive call ended up on that `console.log`  statement that printed the array having one element only. The key is having the function always return something and make it so that the first "parent" call holds the final value you wished.

Comment: There's a clue to help you better explore the execution of your own code and it's using the debugger inside the browser. You can open the devtools and in sources set breakpoints. Or you can even add the statement `debugger;` in any point in your code and if you have the devtools open when the page is running, the debugger will stop on that statement without you setting the breakpoint upfront

Comment: @DiegoD  as i have read the answers yesterday i realised i needed to establish the array as a parameter from the start so  i can work around the deceleration problem & having values sent to the array every time the function calls itself 

i will definitely try to use the debugger and read about it some more , ty for your help diego i appreciate it man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1 -** If you do not want to declare a global variable then you can pass the `storageArray` as an argument which will update every time you call a recursion function.

**Point 2 -** As you declare the `storageArray` variable every time you call the recursion function, it will store only a single element each time. So whether you use push or unshift, both operations are performed on a single element inside an array so you won't see much difference.

Here is a working snippet of passing an array as an argument.

```js
function recursiveCountUp(startNum, endNum, storageArray) {
    if (startNum > endNum) {
        return [endNum];
    } else {
        storageArray.push(startNum);
        recursiveCountUp((startNum + 1), endNum, storageArray);
    }
    return storageArray;
}

let result = recursiveCountUp(4, 11, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is so appreciated thank you for your explination

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd write the code, if I had to use recursion:

```js
function recursiveCountUp(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum>=endNum ? 
    [endNum] : 
    [startNum, ...recursiveCountUp(startNum+1, endNum)]
}
console.log(recursiveCountUp(4,11))
```

Alternatively:

```js
function recursiveCountUp(startNum, endNum, arr=[]) {
  arr.push(startNum);
  if(startNum<endNum) recursiveCountUp(startNum+1, endNum, arr);
  return arr;
}
console.log(recursiveCountUp(4,11))
```

or, without recursion:

```js
function range(startNum, endNum) {
  return Array(Math.max(endNum-startNum+1,0)).fill().map((_,i)=>i+startNum)
}
console.log(range(4,11))
```

Comment: this is a bit too advanced for me as i didn't encounter ...  / fill map .. etc
but i thank appreciate your effort and i will take a look at those solutions as i progress .. ty andrew